# c# copy (not just redirect) stdout of a process not working using joined thread

Tags: c#, stdout

I am trying to capture the stdout of a process started in my code but still put the output to the console app that it is running.

My project is a .net core Windows application.

I attach a procedure thread to the process to get the stdout and in that thread I do a console write to also output it to the attached application. I suspect that it is trying to write it to my applications non existent console instead of the joined process. If so, is there a way to get the output and still have it written to the executed processes console?

Code -

```
    private Process proc = null;
    
    private void WriteStandardOutput()
    {
      using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(exeOutputPath + "\\_out.txt"))
      using (StreamReader reader = proc.StandardOutput)
      {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;

        for (; ; )
        {
          string textLine = reader.ReadLine();

          if (textLine == null)
            break;

          writer.WriteLine(textLine);
          Console.Out.WriteLine(textLine);
        }
      }

      if (File.Exists(exeOutputPath + "\\_out.txt"))
      {
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(exeOutputPath + "\\_out.txt");

        // if the error info is empty or just contains eof etc.

        if (info.Length < 4)
          info.Delete();
      }
    }
    
    
    ///////////////function code 
    
    int exitCode;
  
    if (!File.Exists(exePath) && !exePath.Contains("cmd.exe"))
      throw new Exception("No executable specified for RunExtApp - " + this.name);

    if (exePath.Contains("cmd.exe"))
      runParams = "/K " + runParams;

    //Start the executable
    extApp = new ProcessStartInfo();
    extApp.Arguments = runParams;
    extApp.FileName = exePath; // Path.GetFileName(exePath);
    extApp.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
    extApp.UseShellExecute = false;
    extApp.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    extApp.RedirectStandardError = true;

    // Do you want to show a console window?
    //extApp.WindowStyle = Hidden.ProcessWindowStyle;
    //extApp.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
    using (proc = Process.Start(extApp))
    {
      Thread stdOutThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WriteStandardOutput));
      stdOutThread.IsBackground = true;
      stdOutThread.Name = "StandardOutput";
      stdOutThread.Start();

      proc.WaitForExit();
      stdOutThread.Join();

      // Retrieve the app's exit code
      exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
      proc.Close();
      if (exitCode > 0)
        throw new Exception("Failed to run external code - " + exePath + ".   exit code - " + exitCode.ToString());
    }
```

Test Exe - .net framework console application

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleWriteTester
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          for(int i = 0; i < 30; i ++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Line " + i.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have the method WriteStandardOutput() write the text to an object (string, or equivalent) instead of writing to Console.

Comment: The goal is to write it to the file needed for another process and write it to the console of the EXE it came from.

Comment: You want to write a string to  a stream.  It doesn't matter when you do the write.  The input is a string and the output a stream.

Comment: You said "instead of writing to the Console", I need it in the console. When my app runs the user selected console exe, it is displayed and needs to output the same it does if they were to run it from command line, in it's console.

Comment: You can output to console after getting the string.

Comment: I am fine writing it to a string, but my problem is how do I output it to the Console of the users EXE I am running if Console.Write does not work?

Comment: I think you are having issue writing inside a thread.  If the string is static you should be able to write string from thread.   Then outside thread write to console.  You may need to use Invoke to resolve any cross thread exceptions.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean, I will try it.